# Roblox Group Finder: Locked

Tags: lua, roblox

If it is possible, how do I find if an empty Roblox group is locked? This is my code so far:

```
local group = game:GetService("GroupService")
local id = 0
local thisstop = false
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    wait(2)
    local function pcalltest()
        while wait() do
            print(id)
            local stop = false
            id += 1
            local info = 0
            if stop == false then
                if  group:GetGroupInfoAsync(id) then
                    local info = group:GetGroupInfoAsync(id)
                    print(table.concat(info, ", ", 1, #info))
                    if info["Owner"] then
                        local owner = info["Owner"]["Name"]
                        local id = info["Id"]
                        if owner then
                            local name = info["Name"]
                            local result = name.." (ID: "..id..") is owned by "..owner.."!"
                            print(result)
                            plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel.Text = result
                        end
                    elseif info["Owner"] == nil then
                        local ok = game.ReplicatedStorage.TextButton:Clone()
                        ok.Parent = plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui
                        plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel.Text = "Group found! ID: "..id
                        thisstop= true
                        stop = true
                        repeat
                            wait()
                            ok.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
                                thisstop = false
                                stop = false
                                id += 1
                                ok:Destroy()
                            end)
                        until thisstop == false
                    end
                else
                    id += 1
                end
            end
        end     
    end
    local function pcal()
        local success, errormsg = pcall(pcalltest)
        if success then
            print("Success!")
        else
            warn("Error: "..errormsg)
            id += 1
            pcal()
        end
    end
    pcal()
end)
```

I looked in "GroupService" in the Roblox Creator Documentation, but I don't think I found anything.
Is there any way to make "if a group is 'locked'" finder?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this code is meant to find groups that are abandoned but not locked, for them to be claimed by a user.

The only way I've seen to find if a group is locked or not is through the groups API.

```
/v1/groups/{groupId}
```

That API call will give a response containing a `"publicEntryAllowed": true/false` which would tell you if it's locked or not. The only problem is that ROBLOX's HTTPService doesn't allow calls to its own site. There are proxies that you can host, such as rprxy, but that's for you to decide.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

***GroupService*** in Roblox does not have a direct method to check if a group is locked or not.
However, you can determine if a group is locked or not by checking if the "GroupWall" feature is enabled for the group.
something like this

```
local GroupService = game:GetService("GroupService")
local groupId = --id here

local success, groupInfo = pcall(GroupService.GetGroupInfoAsync, GroupService, groupId)
if success then
    local isGroupWallEnabled = groupInfo["publicEntryAllowed"]
    if isGroupWallEnabled then
        print("Locked")
    else
        print("Not Locked")
    end
else
    warn("Error occurred while fetching group info.")
end
```